# Margin overflow problem

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with some CSS. 
This is my html

```
<body>
<div id="cn">
    <div id="hd">
        <ul>
            <some li's>
        </ul>
    </div><!-- /#hd -->
    <div id="bd">
    </div><!-- /#bd -->
    <div id="ft">
    </div><!-- /#ft -->
</div><!-- /#cn -->
```

and there is my CSS:

```
div#cn {
    position: relative;
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: #f7f7f7;
}

div#cn > * {
    position: relative;
}

div#cn div#hd {
    height: 258px;
    background: #f7f7f7 url(../img/hd.jpg);
}

div#cn div#hd ul {
    margin: 50px 0 0 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
}

div#cn div#hd ul li {
    float: left;
}

div#cn div#hd ul li a {
    display: block;
    height: 35px;
    padding: 20px 25px 0 25px;
    font-weight: bold;
    background: pink url(../img/nava.jpg) right 0 no-repeat;
}
```

Now the margin is not affecting the UL but the Div around it (#hd) in firefox. Its like i had the margin on #hd and not on the ul... Now it gets strange, if i set a border to #hd it works! (or if I palce a nbsp before the UL it works to)

How strange is that? And can someone tell me why this is happening and how i can fix that properly. (it don't wanna set a border to make it work :P )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your margins are collapsing (http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins).

Try:

```
div#cn div#hd ul {display: inline-block}
```

Comment: Didn't you say that this was a firefox problem?

Answer (score 0):

I've just come across a similar problem, and solved it by simply adding some paddings to the parent element.

```
div#cn div#hd{ padding: 1px 0; margin: -1px 0; }
```